# DataPager not working on first click

Tags: c#, asp.net, datapager

i have a user control that i place it on Default.aspx. in Default.aspx i have this code:

```
   ds = FillFromDatabase();
        Session["note"] = ds.Tables[0];
```

and in `usercontorl` i have this code:

```
 if (Session["note"] != null)
        {
            ListView1.DataSource = Session["note"] as DataTable;
            ListView1.DataBind();

        }
```

`listview` has a `datapager` with 5 page. when i click on next page it not wroking when i again click on next it works correctly. any idea?

Comment: where do you populate the session[note]; perhaps on the click event?

Comment: @Pleun yes i fill session["note"] in button click but this line * ds = FillFromDatabase();
        Session["note"] = ds.Tables[0]; * is on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution:

```
protected void ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
        DbAccessor db1 = new DbAccessor();
       ListView1.DataSource = fillFromDb();

        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
```